# SVG subtraction of objects and paths

Tags: python, svg, svg-filters, svg-font

I am trying to create an SVG font, so I need to create some paths.  One of the letters is defined by the following path:

[image: Path]

Which I created with [svgwrite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgwrite), by creating two `circles` and a `rect`, and then using inkscape to take the difference of the two circles and the intersection with the straight line, like so:
[image: Combination]

My question is if I can do this directly with SVG or svgwrite?  Either doing the boolean operations, or creating a path that behaves as the one above.

I've tried to create a black and white circle with a path like:

```
 d="M0,128 A128,128,1,1,0 0 127.9 Z\
  M 32 128 A 96 96 1 1 0 32 127.9 Z"
```

with `fill="#000000", stroke = "none", fill-rule="evenodd"`
However this ring is not recognized by the SVG font editor (it just creates a black disc).

I also tried to create the combination of paths (outer circle, inner circle, horizontal line)

```
d="M0,128 A128,128,1,1,0 0 127.9 Z\
 M 32 128 A 96 96 1 1 0 32 127.9 Z \
M 38 128 l 0 15 l 180 0 l 0 -30 l -180 0 z"
```

but although I can see the right-looking result when I open the SVG, the font editor will not recognize the path created which looks like this:

[image: path generated]

Is there some way to generate programmatically the path of the first picture above?

Comment: Seems like you could do it in SVG as an explicit compound path composed of three separate subpaths -- the outer circle plus the upper and lower almost half-circles (via elliptical arc curve) -- along with the appropriate fill-rule. Your font-editor may then be able to handle this since it wouldn't have to calculate any of the paths itself via shape-differencing.

Comment: @martineau, that's exactly my question. How do you create an << explicit compound path composed of 3 subpaths with elliptical arc curves >>? My attempts (see the d, and fill-rule="evenodd") are in my description, but I don't know how to improve upon them.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the same 3 subpaths. The first would be the outer, a full circle (like you have), but the other two would each be closed elliptical arc curves (the upper and lower partial circles). Unfortunately I can't include an image in my comment.

Comment: Here's an [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/svg_symbol.png) showing the subpaths I think you need.

Answer (score 2):

The first arc has a negative (0) draw angle, the second must have a positive (1) draw angle and drawn from the opposite side to achieve the desired effect.

```py
#--------------------------N-----------↓↓↓-↓↓↓-------------P-↓↓↓-↓↓↓↓↓----------------------------------------------
d="M 0 128 A 128 128 1 1 0 0 127.9 Z M 224 128 A 96 96 1 1 1 224 127.9 Z M 38 128 L 0 15 L 180 0 L 0 -30 L -180 0 Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

following @martineau's suggestion and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737975/circle-drawing-with-svgs-arc-path) SO question, I came to this solution:

- Create a circle made of two halfs
- Creates two smaller half circles (not quite circular)
- then use  [`fill-rule: evenodd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty)  to combine all of them.

  ```
  d="
  M 128, 128                 
  m -128, 0                    
  a 128,128 0 1,0 256,0\    
  a 128,128 0 1,0 -256,0\
  M 32,112 a 1.15 1 0 1 1 194, 0z\
  M 32,142 a 1.15 1 0 1 0 194, 0z\
  "
  ```

which returns something like this:
[image: e letter path from script].
Unfortunately, the Inkscape SVG font editor only renders this:
[image: Imgur]

So I'll have to continue investigating where the problem may come from.  Further suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Filters don't produce paths, they just produce bitmaps (so if you need a path - this is the wrong answer). But Here's a version using an SVG Filter - since you tagged the question with it (won't work in Firefox - can't use objects as feImage inputs yet - you'd have to inline them as data URI).

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <circle id="inner" cx="80" cy="80" r="60" fill="white" />
    <line id="crossbar" x1="20" x2="140" y1="80" y2="80" stroke-width="22" stroke="black"/>
    
    <filter id="combine" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#inner" result="innerwhite"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#crossbar" result="crossbarthing"/>
      <feComposite operator="xor" in="SourceGraphic" in2="innerwhite"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="crossbarthing"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle filter="url(#combine)" cx="100" cy="100" fill=
"black" r="80"/>"
</svg>
```