# How to draw a linear gradient circle by svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

This is my code, but it's not what I wanted.I hope the color distribution is not symmetrical.

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <linearGradient id="linearColors" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
       <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
       <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
       <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
       <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
       <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
   <circle r="120" cx="150" cy="150" class="external-circle" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors)"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image]

I need an effect like this.

[image]

Comment: Just a note, your percentage values aren't symmetrical either!  Shouldn't it be 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100?

Comment: What distribution are you trying to achieve, exactly? x1,y1 is top left, x2,y2 is bottom right and the colors match up correctly the way I see it. No chance you're looking to use a radialGradient, is there?

Comment: @SteveHynding You can see I have just uploaded a picture

Comment: @Kaiido i solve the problem using arcs

Answer (score 10):

before check: [circle-drawing-with-svgs-arc-path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477334/4767343) .... my solution is simple: i divided circle into six arcs, each arc with own lineal gradient

**math explanation:**

> angle = 360 / 6 = 60
>
> Math.sin(Math.PI*60/180)*120 == 103.9230
>
> Math.cos(Math.PI*60/180)*120 == 60.0000

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <linearGradient id="linearColors1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors2" x1="0.5" y1="0" x2="0.5" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors3" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors4" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors5" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors6" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
   <path d="M150 10 a120 120 0 0 1 103.9230 60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors1)" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M253.9230 70 a120 120 0 0 1 0 120"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors2)" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M253.9230 190 a120 120 0 0 1 -103.9230 60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors3)" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M150 250 a120 120 0 0 1 -103.9230 -60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors4)" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M46.077 190 a120 120 0 0 1 0 -120"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors5)" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M46.077 70 a120 120 0 0 1 103.9230 -60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors6)" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you use the d3.js to solve this problem?

Comment: I do not know how to use d3.js, ..... but of course this can make with d3.js ....