# CSS3 Linear Gradient in a circular way

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like this with css gradients:

[image: color wheel]

I have searched a lot and all the gradients are either "Linear" or "Radial". My desired gradient is linear in a circular way!

Comment: Interesting question. But I think it's not possible using just a CSS gradient.

Comment: I came up with a messy solution with css & javascript. I can create many circle slices and color them. But I don't think it's the way to go.

Comment: Actually, that's the best way I can think of using pure CSS.

Comment: This is very highly difficult with CSS. Would be easy with Canvas or SVG. Have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247310/circle-loading-animation/31250354#31250354) for SVG/Canvas implementation. There are also other SVG and CSS (conical gradient) answers which you would find helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*-- Updated with information from early 2022 --*

It's doable now - at least with most browsers. The CSS property [`conic-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient) can easily achieve this:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}
.colorwheel {
    background: conic-gradient(red, yellow, lime, aqua, blue, magenta, red);
    border-radius:50%;
}
.fallback {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fallback box">
    If you can read<br>this, your browser<br>doesn't support<br>conic-gradient yet.
</div>
<div class="colorwheel box"></div>
```

This CSS function is specified in an *editor's draft* of *CSS Images Module Level 4* and is currently implement by most browsers including many mobile browsers. Check [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients) for current support.

Answer (score 6):

This is called Conical Gradient and is not currently possible in pure CSS, but it has been proposed for the CSS Image Values 4 draft. Recently [Lea Verou created a polyfill](http://lea.verou.me/2015/06/conical-gradients-today/) for them, there is also [a PostCSS plugin](https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-conic-gradient) that does the same.

Answer (score 6):

### CSS

This can be completed using multiple sections which are then rotated to create a circle.

```css
.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wheel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
}
.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
}
.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 15em, 15em, 7.5em);
}
.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip: rect(0, 7.5em, 15em, 0);
}
.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}
.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}
.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}
.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}
.color:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #FF3BA7;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.color:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #FF5800;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.color:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #FF8100;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.color:nth-child(10):after {
  background-color: #FEAC00;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.color:nth-child(11):after {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.color:nth-child(12):after {
  background-color: #EDE604;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel">
  <ul class="umbrella">
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To then get the blur, just use the `transform` function to add an appropriate blur.

```css
.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wheel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
}
.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  filter: blur(.75em);
  -webkit-filter: blur(.75em);
  -moz-filter: blur(.75em);
  -o-filter: blur(.75em);
  -ms-filter: blur(.75em);
  filter: url(#blur);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='.75');
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
}
.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 15em, 15em, 7.5em);
}
.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip: rect(0, 7.5em, 15em, 0);
}
.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}
.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}
.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}
.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}
.color:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #FF3BA7;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.color:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #FF5800;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.color:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #FF8100;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.color:nth-child(10):after {
  background-color: #FEAC00;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.color:nth-child(11):after {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.color:nth-child(12):after {
  background-color: #EDE604;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel">
  <ul class="umbrella">
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Please note, in older versions of IE or old browsers, snippets won't work as they use HTML5 technology to run. I recommend testing in a local environment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid CSS doesn't allow for a linear-radial gradient. However, svg provides a solution, albeit crude. See the below topics for a solution.

[How to draw a linear gradient circle by svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147879/how-to-draw-a-linear-gradient-circle-by-svg)

[svg multiple color on circle stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206361/svg-multiple-color-on-circle-stroke)

Comment: nice but the solutions work only for a thin circle outline

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 triangles cuted with common circle. Each triangle is transformed by central projection from long rectangle with linear gradient.
I try it with SVG in Firefox, but Chromium does not support central projection in SVG but supports conical gradients, so see combined version for both browsers.

```html
<svg version="2" viewBox="-207 -207 414 414" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <radialGradient id="gWt">
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff0" offset="1"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <!-- part for firefox: using central projection of 3 rectangles -->
  <linearGradient id="gYM" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100%">
   <stop style="stop-color:#ef08" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fc0" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f90" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f60" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f00" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f06" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f09" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0c" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#e0f8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gCY" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ef8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fc" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f9" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f6" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f0" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#6f0" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#9f0" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#cf0" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fe08" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gMC" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0e8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#c0f" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#90f" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#60f" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#00f" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#06f" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#09f" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0cf" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fe8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect id="r" width="2000" height="700" style="transform:matrix3d(
      -29,0,0,100,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      200,-350,1,1
    ); mix-blend-mode:lighten"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="cc">
  <circle r="200" id="c"/>
 </clipPath>
 <circle r="199" fill="#000"/>
 <g clip-path="url(#cc)" id="m">
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gCY)" transform="rotate(-120)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gYM)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gMC)" transform="rotate(120)"/>
  <!-- for Chrome use conic gradient (does not work with any svg object but with foreign)
   Firefox ignores this object due to unknown keyword in style -->
 <foreignObject width="400" height="400" x="-200" y="-200" style="background:conic-gradient(from 90deg,
   #f00,#f0f,#00f,#0ff,#0f0,#ff0,#f00);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <!-- Points for visual test -->
  <circle cx="-200" r="6" fill="#0ff"/>
  <circle cx="-195.6" cy="-41.6" r="6" fill="#0fc"/>
  <circle cx="-182.7" cy="-81.3" r="6" fill="#0f9"/>
  <circle cx="-161.8" cy="-117.6" r="6" fill="#0f6"/>
  <circle cx="-133.8" cy="-148.6" r="6" fill="#0f3"/>
  <circle cx="-100" cy="-173.2" r="6" fill="#0f0"/>
  <circle cx="-61.8" cy="-190.2" r="6" fill="#3f0"/>
  <circle cx="-20.9" cy="-198.9" r="6" fill="#6f0"/>
  <circle cx="20.9" cy="-198.9" r="6" fill="#9f0"/>
  <circle cx="61.8" cy="-190.2" r="6" fill="#cf0"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="-173.2" r="6" fill="#ff0"/>
  <circle cx="133.8" cy="-148.6" r="6" fill="#fc0"/>
  <circle cx="161.8" cy="-117.6" r="6" fill="#f90"/>
  <circle cx="182.7" cy="-81.3" r="6" fill="#f60"/>
  <circle cx="195.6" cy="-41.6" r="6" fill="#f30"/>
  <circle cx="200" r="6" fill="#f00"/>
  <circle cx="-195.6" cy="41.6" r="6" fill="#0cf"/>
  <circle cx="-182.7" cy="81.3" r="6" fill="#09f"/>
  <circle cx="-161.8" cy="117.6" r="6" fill="#06f"/>
  <circle cx="-133.8" cy="148.6" r="6" fill="#03f"/>
  <circle cx="-100" cy="173.2" r="6" fill="#00f"/>
  <circle cx="-61.8" cy="190.2" r="6" fill="#30f"/>
  <circle cx="-20.9" cy="198.9" r="6" fill="#60f"/>
  <circle cx="20.9" cy="198.9" r="6" fill="#90f"/>
  <circle cx="61.8" cy="190.2" r="6" fill="#c0f"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="173.2" r="6" fill="#f0f"/>
  <circle cx="133.8" cy="148.6" r="6" fill="#f0c"/>
  <circle cx="161.8" cy="117.6" r="6" fill="#f09"/>
  <circle cx="182.7" cy="81.3" r="6" fill="#f06"/>
  <circle cx="195.6" cy="41.6" r="6" fill="#f03"/>
 </g>
 <circle r="200" fill="url(#gWt)"/>
</svg>
```

Offset values is calculated using the formula (for rectangular triangle 350x200):

```
0.5 ± tan(v/255.*pi/3)/350*100.
```

Where `v` is the value of the changing color channel.

HTML version (view the snippet in full window on Chrome)

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.c{
   height:90vmin;
   width:90vmin;
   margin:5vmin;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius:50%;
   position:absolute;
}
.c>div{
   position:relative;
   height:180vmin;
   width:100vmin;
   perspective: 0.40vmin;
   top:-45vmin;
   left:-4.8vmin;
}
.c>div>div{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left:0;
   top:1%;
   height: 98%;
   transform-origin:99.98% 50%;
   position:relative;
   transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -80deg);
   border:black;
}
#YM>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#ef08,#ff0 0.5%,#fc0 18.27%,#f90 29.24%,#f60 37.28%,#f00 50%,#f06 62.72%,#f09 70.76%,#f0c 81.73%,#f0f 99.5%,#e0f8);
}
#MC{
   transform: rotateZ(120deg);
}
#CY{
   transform: rotateZ(-120deg);
}
#MC>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#f0e8,#f0f 0.5%,#c0f 18.27%,#90f 29.24%,#60f 37.28%,#00f 50%,#06f 62.72%,#09f 70.76%,#0cf 81.73%,#0ff 99.5%,#0fe8);
}
#CY>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#0ef8,#0ff 0.5%,#0fc 18.27%,#0f9 29.24%,#0f6 37.28%,#0f0 50%,#6f0 62.72%,#9f0 70.76%,#cf0 81.73%,#ff0 99.5%,#fe08);
}
```

```html
<div class="c"><div id="YM"><div></div></div></div>
<div class="c"><div id="MC"><div></div></div></div>
<div class="c"><div id="CY"><div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG made my work very hard.
The best solution I found is to use multiple circle slices and color them. And it is pure css3.

The question is: How to make the color changes smooth?
I found the answer:
By using blur filters.

Here is the complete solution:
[Conical Gradients in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/conical-gradients-css/)

Comment: I just found out that in IE9+ blur filter does not exist outside canvas and svg. So this method could not be used in IE9+. what a surprise!!!

Comment: That is the reason why I recommended SVG/Canvas but upon seeing your answer I thought you didn't need to support IE9. Have a look at the answer I linked in comment or the polyfill mentioned in Ilya's answer. The polyfill also uses Canvas and/or SVG only.

Comment: Link-only answers are not very useful -- when the link dies or the content changes, the answer loses its value. Please update the answer to include useful content from your link, or this answer risks getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing with an idea for this for my own project. I didn't wanna use 'conic-gradient' as the support is very low for it at this time (mid 2019). so I came up with the following:

```
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 38% 7% ,rgba(255,255,000,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,000,.0) 38%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%,rgba(128,255,000,1) 22%,rgba(128,255,000,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 75% 7% ,rgba(000,255,000,1) 22%,rgba(000,255,000,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 93% 24%  ,rgba(000,255,128,1) 22%,rgba(000,255,128,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%,rgba(000,255,255,1) 22%,rgba(000,255,255,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 93% 75% ,rgba(000,128,255,1) 22%,rgba(000,128,255,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 75% 93%,rgba(000,000,255,1) 22%,rgba(000,000,255,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100% ,rgba(128,000,255,1) 22%,rgba(128,000,255,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 25% 93%,rgba(255,000,255,1) 22%,rgba(255,000,255,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 7% 75%,rgba(255,000,128,1) 22%,rgba(255,000,128,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%,rgba(255,000,000,1) 22%,rgba(255,000,000,.0) 48%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 7% 25%,rgba(255,128,000,1) 22%,rgba(255,128,000,.0) 48%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p5vxek3u/

Its not exact, but its close enough for my needs. I'm using it behind something with alpha transparency so you only get to see a small part at a time.

I thought I'd leave it here in case anyone needed it.