# How to dynamically fill svg circle wtih a multicolored circular gradient?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, svg, gradient

The page I am working on contains a certain gradient that consists of seven colors. The colors in the gradient should go one after another radially, not in a linear way. The circle should be filled with the gradient based on a number from 1 to 100 (including floats) that represents a percentage of a circle that is filled. The number is sent dynamically by the backend and is a student GPA score.
I know that there were similar question here already. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363990/circular-progress-indicator-with-a-color-gradient-with-svgs) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147879/how-to-draw-a-linear-gradient-circle-by-svg). They differ from mine on one key aspect - I have to fill the  element dynamically and I count the circumference of the circle element, so I cannot use multiple paths. And also this cannot just be a linear gradient, otherwise I would've done this already.
Also I don't know how to use d3.js or anything like that.

Please help me, the task is due tomorrow.

[image: here is what I am trying to achieve]
[image: Here is what I have]

```js
    const circle = document.querySelector(".progress-ring__circle");
    const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
    const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

    circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

    function setProgress(percent) {
      const offset = circumference - (percent / 100) * circumference;
      circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
    };

setProgress(75);
```

```css
.progress-ring__circle {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s;
}
```

```html
              <svg class="progress-ring" width="90" height="90">
                <defs>
                  <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
                    <stop offset="5%" stop-color="green" />
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold" />
                  </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle
                  class="progress-ring__circle"
                  stroke="url(#MyGradient)"
                  stroke-width="10"
                  cx="45"
                  cy="45"
                  r="30"
                  fill="none"
                />
              </svg>
```

Comment: First, could you correct the reported error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` that way we're not focusing on fixing the wrong thing(s)?

Comment: done, now everything works