# Width of SVG isn't correct when viewBox is defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to understand why my SVG icon is not rendered correctly. The icon is a little smallest that my SVG element event if the viewBox property was used the same like width\height.

Thanks for any help

As you see the icon is a little bit smallest than the whole SVG element.

[image]

My SVG code.

```html
<svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>1FB31B20-CDD9-43CB-A743-1C613F5D5E0C</title>
  <g fill="#9FA09F" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M7 13.684a6 6 0 1 0 0-12 6 6 0 0 0 0 12zm0 1a7 7 0 1 1 0-14 7 7 0 0 1 0 14z" />
    <path d="M7 7.684a2 2 0 1 0 .001-4 2 2 0 0 0-.001 4zM7 8.684c3 0 3.566 2.116 3.566 2.116.24.488-.019.884-.563.884H3.997c-.55 0-.82-.418-.553-.9 0 0 .556-2.1 3.556-2.1z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually I added the pure code. Image is just to show an example. I'll remove the console if you want.

Comment: Hi Robert. But is it fine to do that? Is it won't break a response design in case of reducing a browser size? (I changed the viewBox prop to : 0,0, 14,15    and it's working).  Thank you so much!

Comment: More code is needed, at least 1 input next to the icon to see it's height.

Answer (score 4):

## View Port

-The viewport is the visible area of an `<svg>`. To set viewport we can use attributes `height` and `width` with `<svg>`.

## View Box

-It allow us to set our graphic and stretch to fit within container. `viewbox` having four property `mix-x`, `min-y`, `width`, `height`. And `min` values represent from what point within the image the `viewBox` should start.

## Example

If we set viewport and `viewbox`,  `width` and `height` same. Then `viewbox` cover entire image.

## Solution

-For your problem you need to reduce size of `viewbox` `width` an `height` property. But as your image size is small you also need to set `width` and `height to get required result.

[JsFiddle Solution with different example](https://jsfiddle.net/6724am45/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much Kashyap for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

If you created the icon, it was draw on the top left corner of the canvas. The actual icon is a `14px x 15px` inside a `24px x 25px` viewbox.

[image][image]

If this was the case, you could either re-draw it centered full width and height of a `24px x 25px` workspace canvas or if you can't re-draw it just try to align it manually as it is.

Anyways, if you wish the latter, here's a flex suggestion to align it with CSS `translate` (tweak values to your benefit):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
svg {
  transform: translate(25%, 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>1FB31B20-CDD9-43CB-A743-1C613F5D5E0C</title>
    <g fill="#9FA09F" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <path d="M7 13.684a6 6 0 1 0 0-12 6 6 0 0 0 0 12zm0 1a7 7 0 1 1 0-14 7 7 0 0 1 0 14z" />
      <path d="M7 7.684a2 2 0 1 0 .001-4 2 2 0 0 0-.001 4zM7 8.684c3 0 3.566 2.116 3.566 2.116.24.488-.019.884-.563.884H3.997c-.55 0-.82-.418-.553-.9 0 0 .556-2.1 3.556-2.1z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Syden for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. As others have pointed out, your viewBox is wrong. Change it to `"0 0 14 14"` to fix that.
2. Secondly, by default, `<svg>` elements are `display: inline-block`, just like other images.  So if they are in a line with other text (inluding `<input>` elements) they will be positioned so that they sit of the text baseline.

There are various way to solve that, but generally you would just change the SVG to `display: block` then use the typical ways that you would align vertically to other things on the line.  Eg. with `float: left` and `margin`.

```css
svg {
  display:block;
  float: left;
}

input {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 14 14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>1FB31B20-CDD9-43CB-A743-1C613F5D5E0C</title>
  <g fill="#9FA09F" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M7 13.684a6 6 0 1 0 0-12 6 6 0 0 0 0 12zm0 1a7 7 0 1 1 0-14 7 7 0 0 1 0 14z" />
    <path d="M7 7.684a2 2 0 1 0 .001-4 2 2 0 0 0-.001 4zM7 8.684c3 0 3.566 2.116 3.566 2.116.24.488-.019.884-.563.884H3.997c-.55 0-.82-.418-.553-.9 0 0 .556-2.1 3.556-2.1z" />
  </g>
</svg>

<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Paul for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing seems to occupy a space much smaller than the viewBox area, just reduce the viewBox size to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Upon inspecting the other path, the vector itself is only 14×14

Comment: Thank you so much Robert for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your icon appears to be offset is because it is not 24 × 25 pixels. The actual bounds of the vector are 14 × 14 pixels.

[image: screenshot]

I would use an SVG editing tool to fine-tune your vector. The vector that you are currently using is very unstable. I had issues opening it up as-is.

I went ahead and tuned your vector and utilized actual circle and arc-paths.

Here is the result. The original vector is a 32 pixel SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <title>1FB31B20-CDD9-43CB-A743-1C613F5D5E0C</title>
  <g id="person-in-circle">
    <circle id="circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15" fill="none"
            stroke="#9FA09F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    <g id="person" fill="#9FA09F">
      <circle id="person-head" cx="16" cy="12" r="5" />
      <path id="person-shoulders" d="M 24 24 a8,8 0 1,0 -16,0" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here is a 16 pixel SVG (Scaled by half)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <title>1FB31B20-CDD9-43CB-A743-1C613F5D5E0C</title>
  <g id="person-in-circle">
    <circle id="circle" cx="8" cy="8" r="7.5" fill="none"
            stroke="#9FA09F" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    <g id="person" fill="#9FA09F">
      <circle id="person-head" cx="8" cy="6" r="2.5" />
      <path id="person-shoulders" d="M 12 12 a4,4 0 1,0 -8,0" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If you want to find out more about how arc-paths work, check out this answer:

> [Circle drawing with SVG's arc path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477334)
>
> ```
> <path 
>    d="
>    M cx cy
>    m -r, 0
>    a r,r 0 1,0 (r * 2),0
>    a r,r 0 1,0 -(r * 2),0
>    "
> />
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Plywhirl for the detailed explanation!