# equivalent to std::nextafter (next representable floating point number) in elm (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, floating-point, elm

Is there a way to get the functionality of c++'s `std::nextafter` in Elm? I'm happy to use an external javascript function if that's the only way.

For background, `std::nextafter` is a function taking a floating point number and returning the next representable floating point number by size.

Comment: X/Y problem: I'm using this to draw a `<path d="..."> where I want an arc that makes a full circle.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477334/320615?

Comment: The increments provided by `nextafter` are very fine compared to what is normally needed for drawing. It seems unlikely `nextafter` would be needed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for X... [nextafter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextafter) library provides this functionality, and I doubt very much whether Elm would have anything built in... it's just not a frequently useful procedure.

As for Y, honestly, you're not going about this the right way. The reason that `nextafter` wasn't added until C++11 is that it's not widely useful. In particular, if you plan to use it to give some interface a number which is strictly greater than a given number, while remaining as close to it as possible, prepare for disappointment. Many such interfaces will do initial operations which can have the effect of abnegating that strict ordering. And if you plan to iterate over *all the numbers* in some range... keep in mind that there are about 4 billion billion of them between 0 and 1.

Comment: There are internal calculations in svg implementations that lose more information than this, so I need to find another solution. Thanks for the answer though!