# Why isnt it possible to draw a full circle with one svg arc segment

Tags: svg, specifications

I looked into this question which basically is the same question: [Circle drawing with SVG's arc path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737975/circle-drawing-with-svgs-arc-path)

But it never gets cleared **WHY** its not possible to draw a full circle with only one arc. SVG arcs allow to specify a largeArcFlag which says: "Take the longer route to the endpoint". So if I have an arc segment which starts and stops at the same point, I would expect that it draws me a full circle when the largeArcFlag is set.

Can someone point me to the specification, saying, that a full circle is just not defined or not allowed?

In my eyes it would totally make sense to allow it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/implnote.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters) says

> If the endpoints (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are identical, then this is equivalent to omitting the elliptical arc segment entirely.

Comment: Strange - but at least its written down somewhere. I will refer to the mailing list then and see if I can get an explanation

Comment: Have you tried doing this on a piece of graph paper with the information you're given if the start/end points are at the same place. There's not a unique solution.

Comment: oh - thats indeed pretty clear. I give it much thougts but didnt see the most obvious. Thanks for your clarification!