# SVG Text does not render in Chrome or Safari

Tags: svg, text

I have some SVG text that works fine on Firefox but in Chrome and Safari does not appear.

I have tried:

- Adding padding to the svg container in case the text was being
  cut-off,
- Removing [xml:space="preserve'] from the text,
- Adding a fill color inline.

```
<svg class="fraction_spinner" width="64" height="64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="CS1_01-intro" cx="32" cy="32" r="25" fill="transparent"/>
    <text class="spinner-text spinner-text__casestudy" xml:space="preserve">
        <textPath xlink:href="#CS1_01-intro">Longform  case  study</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I expect the text to render as it does in Firefox, but to no avail in Chrome and Safari

Comment: I don't think all browsers support setting textPath to non-path shapes.

Comment: Only Firefox so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a path instead of the circle:

```html
<svg class="fraction_spinner" width="64" height="64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!--<circle id="CS1_01-intro" cx="32" cy="32" r="25" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"/>-->
  
  <path id="CS1_01-intro"  d="M57,32A25,25 0 0 1 7,32  A25,25,0 0 1 57,32z" />
    <text class="spinner-text spinner-text__casestudy" font-size="16" fill="black">
        <textPath xlink:href="#CS1_01-intro">Longform  case  study</textPath>
    </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: This is perfect - how did you calculate the path?

Comment: @noahscott See the second link in my answer there are dozens of ways to do it all documented there.

Comment: I considered the center of the circle at x:32, y:32. The radius of the circle is 25. In order to draw the path you move to x = center.x + radius, y=center.y: `M57,32`. Next you draw an arc from the actual point. The radiuses for the arc are 25,25. The arc ends at x=center.x - radius, y=center.y: `A25,25 0 0 1 7,32`  Next you draw another arc from the actual point to the starting point: `A25,25,0 0 1 57,32`

Comment: @enxaneta well explained, I will go through and amend my other shapes now.

Comment: @robert-longson thank you again reading through now to substitute my other shapes.

Answer (score 3):

One of the enhancements in the SVG 2 specification is that textPath elements no longer need only point to path elements. [They should now be able to point to any shape](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextPathElement). Firefox has implemented that part of the SVG 2 specification, other browsers have not yet done so.

In fairness there are parts of SVG 2 that other browsers have implemented that Firefox has not.

You can [draw a circle using a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737975/circle-drawing-with-svgs-arc-path) instead which will work in all browsers.

Comment: Oh man, that one guy has the best answer for drawing circles with paths.

Comment: Robert thank you. Switching from <shape> to an equivalent <path> has solved it.