# Is it accurate to conclude the radius of a circle given 4 bazier curves in svg?

Tags: svg, bezier

I have used **svg2paths2**, and wanted to figure out what is the position and radius of a circle, I have noticed the circle is consructed by 4 CubicBezier, as follow:

```
Path(CubicBezier(start=(127.773+90.5469j), control1=(127.773+85.7656j), control2=(123.898+81.8906j), end=(119.121+81.8906j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(119.121+81.8906j), control1=(114.34+81.8906j), control2=(110.465+85.7656j), end=(110.465+90.5469j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(110.465+90.5469j), control1=(110.465+95.3281j), control2=(114.34+99.1992j), end=(119.121+99.1992j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(119.121+99.1992j), control1=(123.898+99.1992j), control2=(127.773+95.3281j), end=(127.773+90.5469j)))
```

I have read the standard approach is to divide the circle into four equal sections, and fit each section to a cubic Bézier curve.

So I was wondering is it accurate to say the Radius of the circle is

```
(q1.start.real - q3.start.real)/2
```

## or

```
(q2.start.imag - q4.start.imag)/2
```

And the center of the circle is:

```
c_x = (q1.start.real + q1.end.real) / 2
c_y = (q1.start.imag + q1.end.imag) / 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, since you're using a library, but I wrote a single path solution that takes into account desired radius and position: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477334/49478

Comment: It sure sounds like a little google and https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic would have helped here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [`svg.path`](https://pypi.org/project/svg.path/) library in python, or `svg2paths2` is related.

```py
from svg.path import Path, Line, Arc, CubicBezier, QuadraticBezier, Close

path = Path(CubicBezier(start=(127.773+90.5469j), control1=(127.773+85.7656j), control2=(123.898+81.8906j), end=(119.121+81.8906j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(119.121+81.8906j), control1=(114.34+81.8906j), control2=(110.465+85.7656j), end=(110.465+90.5469j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(110.465+90.5469j), control1=(110.465+95.3281j), control2=(114.34+99.1992j), end=(119.121+99.1992j)),
 CubicBezier(start=(119.121+99.1992j), control1=(123.898+99.1992j), control2=(127.773+95.3281j), end=(127.773+90.5469j)))
 
 q1 = path[0]
 q2 = path[1]
 q3 = path[2]
 q4 = path[3]
```

`.real` is the X coordinate
`.imag` is the Y coordinate

There's a very slight error in accuracy in the drawing program you are using and it's not at all an issue unless you want extreme accuracy.

`(q1.start.real - q3.start.real) / 2 # 8.6539`  is the radius in this case.
`(q4.start.imag - q2.start.imag)/2 # 8.6543` is also the radius.

`(q1.start.real - q1.end.real) # 8.6539` is again also the radius.
This accesses the same property, `q1` of `path` and I' prefer it to the two above ways because it's accessing one property not two.

**Below shown by green circle in diagram**
`c_x = (q1.start.real + q1.end.real) / 2 # 123.447` not center x
`c_y = (q1.start.imag + q1.end.imag) / 2 # 86.21875` not center y

**Below shown by red circle in diagram**
`c_x = q1.end.imag # 119.121`  this is center x
`c_y = q1.start.real # 90.5469` this is center y

To explain how serious the error in accuracy, the pink circle uses `8.6543` radius, below it is `8.6539` in green, perhaps viewable with an extreme zoom. But this does illustrate how important or not the decimal points can be.

Consider using  numbers under 100 and as few decimal points as possible, especially understanding a new idea. Shorter text-length numbers vastly improves readability, understanding no end.
I often use just numbers below ten.
Note: you are drawing the circle counter-clockwise. Clockwise is the usual way.

[image: showing a circle made from four cubic beziers]

Comment: Thanks @Owain Evans, I agree my foolish mistake!
thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Really so easily done, there's so much to be said for setting things up right from the start and then things working as planned!