# svg: Convert outline path to path

Tags: svg

Below is an svg path (the points) which, when given a thickness, displays the grey shape.  I have an svg with the **outline** of the grey shape, and I would like to generate an approximation (I'm assuming the original is impossible to get back) of the original path.  Ideally it would work with shapes that intersect, like a lowercase 'e'.

[image]

The opposite of this: [svg: generate 'outline path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416693/svg-generate-outline-path/13445211)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit beyond the scope of a SO answer.  However there is plenty of information out there on the web.  Converting a bitmap to vectors is called "vectorization".  The class of algorithms that attempts to get the "skeleton" of the shape is known as "thinning".  Google those three terms.

Most of these algorithms are designed to work with bitmaps, but they should be a useful starting point for your situation.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the right words to search.  I am going with this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm