# Is CSS for SVG "standard" CSS?

Tags: html, css, validation, svg

I'd like to style some SVG sprites using an external stylesheet, as detailed in this [Sitepoint tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/) and W3C's [Styling with SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS).

However, the CSS isn't very, er, *standard*:

```
rect {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 3
}
```

as it doesn't validate with the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator).

What gives?

Comment: While you an style SVGs using css, not all SVG-legal styles are valid css, basically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is CSS for SVG “standard” CSS?

No, it is not. It makes use of the CSS *language*, but it is not in the CSS property specification. It's only part of the SVG specification. It's quite similar to using non-standard vendor extensions, in that while prefixes are defined in the CSS grammar, prefixed properties don't actually validate as CSS solely because they're non-standard.

You're supposed to choose the SVG validation profile when validating your code, but it doesn't appear to work; it spits just as many errors as validating according to the CSS spec would. In that case, then it's probably a validator bug.

Answer (score 9):

To validate SVG using the W3C CSS Validator, under "More Options" change the *profile* to SVG

Answer (score 4):

Some properties are standard CSS e.g. display, and some aren't; they apply only to SVG content e.g. fill. They're all [listed here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html).

I don't think there's an easy to digest list of which is which but if you click on an individual property such as [display](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#DisplayProperty) in the [SVG specification property list](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html) (display happens to be a standard CSS property) then you get this text in the SVG standard at the end of the definition:

*Except for any additional information provided in this specification, the normative definition of the ‘display’ property is the CSS2 definition ([CSS2], section 9.2.6).*