# W3C CSS validator error: 'Property text-rendering doesn't exist : geometricPrecision'

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I went to the W3C's CSS validator website, https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and put the URL for a website I am working on into it to see if it had any CSS errors.

Straight away I was thrown off by the following

> Property text-rendering doesn't exist : geometricPrecision

I cannot find anything in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) that says the attribute is not valid, although it had less-than-ideal browser support.

Is the error going to cause an issue and should I include a fallback attribute?

Comment: See also: [Is CSS for SVG “standard” CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470985/is-css-for-svg-standard-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that MDN page you linked:

> The text-rendering property is an SVG property that is not defined in any CSS standard. However, Gecko and WebKit browsers let you apply this property to HTML and XML content on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

`text-rendering` is for SVG, not for HTML.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#TextRenderingProperty

Since it is not *defined in any CSS standard* the validator rightfully says so.

Comment: I wasn't aware that SVG properties were unconsidered in the W3C CSS spec. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure to select a validation profile that includes SVG in the "More options" section as this property is not part of CSS 3