# SVG shape stack so that shapeB is bound inside shapeA but shapeA fill is below shapeB

Tags: svg

I'm pretty sure this is either incredibly easy or one of those disappointing things to add to my SVG wish list:

Suppose I have a `rect` like so:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="800 fill="gold" stroke="red" stroke-width="16" />
```

And I also have a `circle, like this:

```
<circle cx="800" cy="0" r="250" fill="#c06" stroke="#930" stroke-width="12" />
```

Kind of close to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb2nV/).

1. Is it possible to define the `circle` as visible above the `rect` but also define the `rect` as the "visible area" for the `circle` so that the `circle` is clipped (not visible) where it does not intersect/overlap with the `rect`
2. If this is possible, is it further possible (assuming it's not the default behavior) to define the "visible" area as the filled area of the `rect` so that the stroke is still considered outside of the visible area and the `circle` appears to be under the stroke but above the fill of the `rect` (like a shape under a picture frame)?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach that doesn't use a `<clipPath>` (since you hate them so much :)

```html
 <svg version="1.1">
    
        <rect x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400"
              fill="gold" stroke="red" stroke-width="6"/>         
        <svg x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400" overflow="hidden">
           <circle cx="394" cy="-6" r="125"
                   fill="#c06" stroke="#930" stroke-width="6"/>
        </svg>
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: I thought overflow could only be used on markers and patterns?

Comment: overflow works on `<svg>` elements and it's the default for inner `<svg>` elements so it's not actually necessary here.

Comment: The overflow attribute is necessary here since we are using it to achieve the clipping effect.

Answer (score 2):

Like this then...

```
<svg version="1.1">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="frame">
        <use xlink:href="#r"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<rect id="r" x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400" 
      fill="gold" stroke="red" stroke-width="6"/>
<circle cx="400" cy="0" r="125" fill="#c06" stroke="#930" stroke-width="6" 
            clip-path="url(#frame)"/>
</svg>
```

For part 2 just draw the stroke as an additional rect on top.

```
<svg version="1.1">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="frame">
        <use xlink:href="#r"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<rect id="r2" x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400" 
      fill="gold"/>
<circle cx="400" cy="0" r="125" fill="#c06" stroke="#930" stroke-width="6" 
            clip-path="url(#frame)"/>
<rect id="r" x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400" 
      fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is clever, in a cheeky way. Will test.

Comment: Have you been speaking to my Mother? She said as much about me when I was 7.

Comment: I've been too busy trying to explain to my mother why she needs to stop using tabled-layouts and direct mysql inserts. She called me "snarky" the other day. I digress. Your trick is quite neat and works except that SVG, as usual, favors the center of the stroke as where a shape starts, not the inside edge. I thought I'd be so smart and apply a `scale(stroke-width)` to the `clipPath`, but was quickly reminded that `scale` units are a percentage, not the view units. Any thoughts on how to reliably decrease the clipPath `rect` to the inner area? (further warning, it also has rounded corners).

Comment: I suspect you'll need to clip to a custom rect or path.

Comment: and we're back to my svg wishlist. I went ahead and took my rounded rectangle backdrop and hide everything else; copied it to just below and removed stroking and set a different fill so I could find which numbers would fit right along the inside edge so it looked like butter on toast. Found the numbers (basically subtracting half the stroke-length in some places and add the full stroke-length in others, etc) , looked good, made that my clipPath, and of course...there is a slight hairline gap. i could almost cry and I just know buried in that damn spec there is some convoluted solution.

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle we can improve for you then.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is, I think. Using the suggested workaround for forcing the stroke orientation ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn ) I got a somewhat cleaner implementation than using a hard-coded clipPath shape. Then I made the colors loader and zoomed into that hairline split. The issue is that the clipped circle path is clipped at the inner arc of a rounded rectangle, so it's kinda like `(⁀`, opposing arcs trying to meet at one clean point. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/GmrpW/

Answer (score 1):

Blah, knew it would be easier to find if I wrote it out as a question. The solution (though not my favorite and a better one is welcome) is to use a `clipPath` element. Using the example from the fiddle in question:

```
<g>
    <clipPath id="frame">
        <rect x="6" y="6" 
              height="250" width="400" stroke-width="6"/>
    </clipPath>
</g>

<rect x="6" y="6" height="250" width="400" 
      fill="gold" stroke="red" stroke-width="6"/>
<circle cx="400" cy="0" r="125" fill="#c06" stroke="#930" stroke-width="6" 
            clip-path="url(#frame)"/>
```

Comment: What aspects of this solution are you unhappy about?

Comment: I would prefer if I could set the clip-path to the shape in the viewport and not have to define it separately with a designated `clipPath` element. I'm sure I could define it once and then reuse it in both contexts via `use` but that's really just saving bytes, whereas I would prefer to semantically show that the circle is clipped (or framed) by the lower rect.