# SVG stroke drawn clipped

Tags: css, svg

I have `<svg>` inside of a `<div>`, but the stroke is giving me issues, it's being clipped by the `div`'s bounding box I think, not sure.

On Chrome and FireFox, the stroke is being clipped.

Surprisingly, on IE11 it's not clipped, but that's still not correct, it should instead be drawn inside the `svg`. Because if I put two `div` elements near each other, I don't want to see stroke of one of the `svg` being drawn on the other. BUT, if there's no other way, this would still be an acceptable solution to me.

Ideally what I need is for the `svg` to draw its stroke inside. But even how IE 11 is doing would be an acceptable solution for me for now.

```css
.container
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" 
       baseProfile="full"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       width="100%" 
       height="100%"
       fill="yellow"
       stroke-width="10"
       stroke="green">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

I need a solution which works for any svg, the `circle` is just an example

Comment: At present that's not possible. Strokes are in fact drawn half on one side of the path and the other half on the inside. There is no `stroke-position` property. You'll just have to adjust the viewbox of your SVG.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn?

Comment: @Harry Is it really related? I'm not looking to control the stroke really, I was thinking there could be something related to the `div` or `svg`, like margins or padding or something

Comment: If the question is really a duplicate maybe I delete or close this question?

Comment: @DonBox: I think it is (but not sure which is why I just left a comment and didn't vtc). The "control" they mean is about where the stroke is drawn. By default, I think it is drawn half inside and half outside in SVG.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there's no good workaround

Comment: Is there a way to make it draw without clipping? Even if it's drawing outside of the `<div>`. Just like IE is doing

Comment: @Harry I updated my question. Even how IE11 is drawing it would be an acceptable solution, so my question is definitely not a duplicate of that question. Could you please remove the "duplicate" status?

Comment: @DonBox: Did you check the two bullet points in Phrogz' answer in that thread? That would be the solution/workaround. I am not convinced about it being a dupe or not, so I will let the community decide on it. Since you've edited the question, it will go to the review queue anyway.

Comment: For some reason it's not possible to send in another answer but I think you are simply looking for  `overflow: visible;`  style on the SVG itself. You'll see the stroke not clipped.  I don't think you meant what photoshop has for borders as inside / outside / center, that would be just a workaround, drawing the stroke inside the circle. Most user agents are showing svg with hidden overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The stroke doesn't count with the total radius. **Reduce the radius**:

```css
.container
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" 
       baseProfile="full"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       width="100%" 
       height="100%"
       fill="yellow"
       stroke-width="10"
       stroke="green">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to make it work for any svg. This is just an example. Sorry if I wasn't clear, I will update the question