# issue with SVG stroke inside div

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to draw an SVG inside a `div` and fill it. If the SVG has `stroke` set, it's drawn outside the `div`.

I see that `svg` with `width=100%` doesn't take into account the stroke width.

```css
.shape {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
svg {
  overflow: hidden;  // IE11 has 'visible' as default
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" viewBox="0,0,100,50">
    <polygon points="0,50 100,50 50,0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

How to make the SVG fill the parent taking into account stroke width?

It should be something like this:

[image]

This has to work for any SVG, the triangle is just an example.

With the browser dev tool open in Chrome for example, if I hover over the `polygon`, it shows its bounding box taking into account the stroke. I wonder if that's available only to the web-browser or it can be achieved in code too. Or maybe it's not the right direction.

Another thing I tried is use an `<img>` and load the SVG into it. Same result.

Comment: As I believe I commented earlier. You can't yet. You have to build the SVG Viewbox to take account of any possible stroke.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn

Comment: @Paulie_D But http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/ somehow does it. Make a triangle, set stroke thickness to something like 20 and check out the hover selection rectangle.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think the questions are related, I'm not looking into controlling the stroke location.

Comment: Well they kinda *are*. The viewbox defines the canvas area of the SVG. Your polygon is tightly fitted to the *exact* edges of the SVG so any stroke will be clipped by the viewbox and not be visible.

Comment: Since I know controlling the `stroke-width` location is not possible, I'm obviously not looking to solve with it. That's why my question is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Then I don't know what you are asking. The stroke is outside the viewbox...and so isn't visible. I can't say much more than that.

Comment: I figured out how http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/ is doing it. It's just setting the `outline` on the hover selector. Not a solution for me however :(

Comment: @Paulie_D I need to draw SVG with stroke inside `div` with the SVG filling the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to change your polygon points in this example!

Or im missing something here?!

```css
.shape {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
svg {
  overflow: hidden;  // IE11 has 'visible' as default
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" viewBox="0,0,100,50">
    <polygon points="10,50 90,50 50,10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: and how did you come up with those numbers? this has to work for any SVG