# Dynamic svg width/height after applying a stroke

Tags: svg

I made an svg with a masked image and applied a stroke to the mask:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
<defs>
    <g id="path">
        <path fill="#ffffff"
            d="m380.42 600l -235.11 123.61 44.9 -261.8 -190.21 -185.41 262.87 -38.2 117.56 -238.2 117.56 238.2 262.87 38.2 -190.21 185.41 44.9 261.8 z"/>
    </g>

    <mask id="image-mask">
        <use xlink:href="#path" overflow="visible"/>
    </mask>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#path" overflow="visible" stroke="red" stroke-width="20"/>

<image width="781" height="744" xlink:href="cat3.jpg" mask="url(#image-mask)"/>

</svg>
```

Unfortunately parts of the stroke get cut off and the result is this:

[image]
The top/left part of the border are cut off.

Is there any way to make them visible without modifying the width/height and viewBox by hand?

Comment: your shape is bigger than the svg canvas.

Comment: not sure if the shape itself is bigger, but the stroke is bigger than the shape and thats why it gets cut off

Comment: So modify the viewBox or translate the shape (and maybe modify the viewBox) or reduce the stroke-width.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you could translate the path away from the edge of the SVG. Another option would be to use this technique using `clipPath` to bring your stroke lines 'inside' the shape rather than outside which is what is causing the lines to be clipped off the edge of the drawing (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="781px" height="744px">
  <defs>

      <path fill-opacity="0" id="path"
          d="m380.42 600l -235.11 123.61 44.9 -261.8 -190.21 -185.41 262.87 -38.2 117.56 -238.2 117.56 238.2 262.87 38.2 -190.21 185.41 44.9 261.8 z"></path>

      <clipPath id="clip">
        <use xlink:href="#path" />
      </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image width="781" height="744" xlink:href="cat3.jpg" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#path" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>

</svg>
```

Also, note that I've brought the `image` element before `use` so that the stroke lines are drawn over the image, and applied `fill-opacity="0"` to the `path` so the image can be seen through the shape.