# Stroke SVG Path only inside or only outside

Tags: html, css, svg, stroke

Consider 2 html svg paths , a square (class `inside`) and a rectangle (class `outside`) having same height. When I apply `stroke-width: 10px`, the stroke gets applied `5px` inside and `5px` outside. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3h5dmk0/9/)

[image]

How do I stroke only inside or only outside?

```
.inside { 
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-mode: inside;     // property does not exist
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.outside {
   stroke: #333;
   stroke-mode: outside;   // property does not exist
   stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

If there is no such property, is there a workaround to achieve something like:

[image]

Comment: changing the size of the inside of the inside rect is no option?

Comment: It would work for simple paths like rectangles, but will it work for complex SVG containing multiple paths, for example, like a circle removed from a square?

Comment: you probably want to have a look at clip-paths like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162431/4428236, seems to be the only solution currently working as the SVG working group has failed to implement stroke-control properties from multiple proposals...

Comment: yeah thats true. when i create svgs i never use strokes just fill. When i want to have a border around something i just draw the path like this.

Comment: You can give the illusion that you stroke only outside by using the [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) attribute which lets you control the order in which the fill and stroke (and painting markers) are drawn. If you use `paint-order: stroke;`  svg will draw the stroke first and then fill. So the inner half of the stroke will be masked by the fill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comment above by *@enxaneta* is exactly right.

Normally, where a filled rectangle is `48px` wide and has a `stroke` with a `stroke-width` of `12px`, the rectangle will display with:

- a `12px` wide border
- an apparent width of `36px`

Why `36px` rather than `48px`?

Because the `12px`-wide stroke painted along the left side of the rectangle is obscuring `6px` of the rectangle and the`12px`-wide stroke painted along the right side of the rectangle is obscuring `6px` of the rectangle.

See this example where the `stroke` has 50% opacity - you can see that half of the `stroke` overlaps the `fill`:

```css
svg rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 12px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

---

**Solution to create an Outer Border of 12px:**

To create an *Outer Border*, the solution is to paint the stroke *first* and *then* paint the fill over the top.

We can achieve this using:

```
paint-order: stroke;
```

Now the rectangle will display with:

- an apparent `6px` wide border (because half the width of the `12px` wide border is obscured by the `fill` painted over the top)
- a width of `48px`

```css
svg rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 12px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

Finally, to ensure the rectangle displays with:

- a `12px` wide border
- a width of `48px`

change the `stroke-width` from `12px` to **24px** (i.e. double the intended display width):

```css
svg rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 24px;      /* double the intended display width */
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

---

**Solution to create an Inner Border of 12px:**

To create an *Inner Border*, we need *three steps* instead of two.

The first two steps are straightforward:

- double the `stroke-width` (just as with the outer border)
- use `paint-order: fill` (instead of `paint-order: stroke`)

```css
svg rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 24px;      /* double the intended display width */
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: fill;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

The **third step** is to define and apply a `<clipPath>` which exactly duplicates the shape which is to have an *Inner Border*.

For instance, if the shape is:

```
<rect width="200" height="100" />
```

Then the `<clipPath>` should be:

```
<clipPath id="my-clip-path">
  <rect width="200" height="100" /> <!-- Same as the shape -->
</clipPath>
```

**Working Example:**

```css
#my-rect {
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 24px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: fill;
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}

#my-rect,
#my-clip-path-rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="my-clip-path">
      <rect id="my-clip-path-rect" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect id="my-rect" />
</svg>
```

---

**All of the rectangles together:**

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

svg:nth-of-type(1) rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 12px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

svg:nth-of-type(2) rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 24px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

svg:nth-of-type(3) rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 24px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: stroke;
}

#svg3clip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

svg:nth-of-type(4) rect {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 24px;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  paint-order: fill;
  clip-path: url(#svg3clip);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>

<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svg3clip">
      <rect />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect />
</svg>

<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/paint-order
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Thanks, that works for outside border. Is there a workaround for inside border?

Comment: I had a think about this, @SaravanabalagiRamachandran and I came up with a solution for an *Inside Border* using `paint-order: fill` and a `<clipPath>` SVG element (combined with the `clip-path` CSS property). See above for full details.

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate it. I would like to note that this inside stroke workaround is limited by the fact that we need to duplicate the shape and use it to clip it. I wish there is a way to clip the object to itself removing the need for duplication.

Comment: Yes - you should be able to do exactly that, @SaravanabalagiRamachandran, by taking advantage of SVG's very useful `<use>` element. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Answer (score 0):

I use two `rect`s to simulate the border.

The first `rect` has the dimensions you want in the end.
The second `rect` is on top and is twice the `stroke-width` smaller in height and width and shifted to x and y by `stroke-width`.

An example for a `rect` with width and height *100*, and *10* `stroke-width`

```css
.rect-stroke {
  x: 10px;
  y: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  stroke-width: 0;
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.rect-fill {
  x: 20px;
  y: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  stroke-width: 0;
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<rect class="rect-stroke" />
<rect class="rect-fill" />
```

There is a restriction if you want to use transparent colors.