# Is there a method to ensure that an SVG ellipse, which has a stroke width of 40px, is of the same size as another ellipse that does not have a stroke?

Tags: css, svg, ellipse

I want to customize a stroke for an SVG ellipse, placing the stroke inside the ellipse. If I set the stroke property, I get the stroke divided, with half inside and half outside the ellipse. To achieve my goal, I tried placing a smaller ellipse inside the real ellipse, setting a stroke for the smaller ellipse, and setting its fill to none.

However, I noticed that the total size of the smaller ellipse is slightly larger than the real ellipse. I suspect that the formula used to calculate the rx and ry of the smaller ellipse may not be correct. I've been making the rx and ry of the real ellipse subtract half the stroke width.

I would like to know if there is a more precise formula for calculating the rx and ry of the smaller ellipse, or if there is another method to draw my stroke inside the real ellipse.

Edit: Use clip-path can hide the extra erea, but it may cause performance issue in my project, so I want to know if there is a 'better' way. And I also want to understand why there exists some extra area.

Thanks for any help! Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/GReKMRJ

```js
var ellipseElement = document.getElementById("myEllipse");
var strokeElement = document.getElementById("myStroke");
var initialRx = parseFloat(ellipseElement.getAttribute("rx"));
var initialRy = parseFloat(ellipseElement.getAttribute("ry"));
var strokeWidth = 40;
var halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2.0;
var strokeRx = initialRx - halfStrokeWidth;
var strokeRy = initialRy - halfStrokeWidth;
console.log(strokeRx, strokeRy);
strokeElement.setAttribute("rx", strokeRx);
strokeElement.setAttribute("ry", strokeRy);
strokeElement.setAttribute("stroke-width", strokeWidth);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ellipse id="myEllipse" cx="150" cy="100" rx="100" ry="50" fill="green" />
  <ellipse id="myStroke" fill="none" cx="150" cy="100" stroke="red" stroke-opacity=0.5 />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can try to use a wide stroke (2 times wider than needed - in your example stroke-width="80") and clip the shape with itself

Comment: @enxaneta Yes, you are right. I can use clip-path to hide the extra erea. But clip-path maybe have performance issue in my program. So I tried to avoid use it.

Comment: We may see an implementation of `stroke-align` in the next years. See also related post ["Can you control how an SVG's stroke-width is drawn?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn/). Currently you need to apply work arounds like clip-path

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks for giving me this good related post. Yeah, maybe `clip-path` is my best choice now.

Comment: My pleasure. You may consider to mark @ccprog's answer as accepted as it also nails the geometry problem introduced by strokes.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks for your kind suggestion. I have accepted it. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fall victim to a rule of geometry: If you draw a path at a fixed distance from the outline of an ellipse, it is not an ellipse. That is relatively easy to see if you draw the path inside, resulting in a smaller size, but it also holds true for paths outside. The geometrical proof is not something to be explained here. If you are interested, you should ask at math.stackexchange.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <ellipse cx="150" cy="100" rx="80" ry="30" fill="none" stroke="darkgreen" stroke-width="40" />
  <ellipse cx="150" cy="100" rx="80" ry="30" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  <ellipse cx="150" cy="100" rx="60" ry="10" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  <ellipse cx="150" cy="100" rx="100" ry="50" fill="none" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

You won't be able to draw what you want to achieve if you combine two ellipses with different axis sizes. Instead, the best way is clipping away the part of the stroke lying outside the geometric path by using the same definition twice:

- define the geometry of your ellipse inside the definition of a `<clipPath>`
- reference the ellipse in a `<use>` element and set fill and stroke to your liking
- clip the `<use>` element with a `clip-path` presentation attribute or CSS property.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <ellipse id="myEllipse" cx="150" cy="100" rx="100" ry="50" />
  </clipPath>
  <use href="#myEllipse" fill="green" stroke="red" stroke-width="80" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It'a a good way to eliminate the extra erea. I want to know if there exists another way to achive my goal wihout `clip-path`,  because I afraid `clip-path` will have performace issue. Thx again!

Comment: Honestly, I can imagine no way in which performance will be impaired by application of a clip-path. In contrast to masking, there is no need for renderers to perfom a composition operation. Instead, they can just compute a new outline path for the area to be colored - something that needs to be done anyway when converting a stroke definition to a colored area.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I'll test the perfomance using your method in my project tomorrow.  Thx again!

Comment: I have tested this method. It seems like it does not have a performance issue. Thanks!