# Scaleable css percentage ring

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to convert the code below basically into a scaleable version, I've tried using vw and vh, %values etc etc and I can't seem to get the right balance of values which work. Any help is appreciated.

This codepen might also help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPNgvP

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 18px solid #dd1111;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 57px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: load-arrow 1.6s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: load-arrow 1.6s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes load-arrow {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 55px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load-arrow {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 55px);
  }
}
.pie {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 140px;
  background-color: #DD1111;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.pie .title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pie1 .inner-right {
  transform: rotate(160deg);
  animation: load-right-pie-1 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation: load-right-pie-1 1s linear;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
}
@keyframes load-right-pie-1 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(160deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load-right-pie-1 {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
  }
}
.outer-left {
  clip: rect(0px 70px 140px 0px);
}
.outer-right {
  clip: rect(0px 140px 140px 70px);
}
.inner-left {
  background-color: #710000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px 70px 140px 0px);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.inner-right {
  background-color: #710000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px 70px 140px 0px);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.content span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: load-content 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation: load-content 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes load-content {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes load-content {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pie pie1">
  <div class="title">Twitter</div>
  <div class="outer-right mask">
    <div class="inner-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer-left mask">
    <div class="inner-left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>44%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be simplified to less than 10 lines(including animation) if you use `svg`.

Comment: I have never used SVG hence why I'm not using it... but feel free to show me how

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479185/svg-donut-slice-as-path-element-annular-sector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify your code and make it dynamic using `svg` and JavaScript.

What this code does?

1. Extract the percentage value from the `text` tag(s), calculates the angle and stores it for the animation.
2. Animates the dark colored part from `theta = 0` to the calculated angle(s).

Things you could do using this approach:

1. You could dynamically set the percentage by simply changing the `44%` in the `text` tags.

   - Valid formats ----> `-%`|`--%`|`---%`, Including float values.
2. You could change the animation speed by changing the `t` variable.
3. You could also make it responsive.

---

<kbd>**Responsive demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/pvRqMW)**</kbd> ---> **The `width` and `height` of the `svg` depends on the `#container`'s `width`.**

```js
var dark = document.getElementById('dark'),
  t = 5,
  percentage = parseInt(document.getElementById('perc').innerHTML.slice(0, -1), 10),
  theta = 0,
  maxTheta = (180 * percentage) / 50,
  radius = document.getElementById('svg').getBBox().width / 2;
dark.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

var animate = setInterval(function() {
  theta += 0.5;
  var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180) * radius + ',' + Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180) * -radius + 'z';
  dark.setAttribute('d', d);
  if (theta > maxTheta) {
    clearInterval(animate);
  }
}, t);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="140" height="140" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
  <path id="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
  <path id="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
  <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
  <text id="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">44%</text>
</svg>
```

---

To put multiple percentage rings, you could use `class`es instead of `id`s. Again, you do not need to make any changes to the JavaScript code, simply change the percentage in the `text` tags.

[image]

<kbd>**[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/yygZJK)**</kbd>

```js
var dark = document.getElementsByClassName('dark'),
  radius = document.getElementsByClassName('svg')[0].getBBox().width / 2,
  t = 0.5,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  theta = {},
  maxTheta = calcTheta(document.getElementsByClassName('perc')),
  intervals = [];

function calcTheta(el) {
  var jbo = {};
  for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    theta[i] = 0;
    dark[i].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
    jbo[i] = (180 * parseInt(el[i].innerHTML.slice(0, -1), 10)) / 50;
  }
  return jbo;
}

var anim = function(j) {
  return function() {
    theta[j] += 0.5;
    var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[j] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + Math.sin(theta[j] * Math.PI / 180) * radius + ',' + Math.cos(theta[j] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius + 'z';
    dark[j].setAttribute('d', d);
    if (theta[j] > maxTheta[j]) {
      clearInterval(intervals[j]);
    }
  }
};

for (var j = 0; j < dark.length; j++) {
  intervals.push(setInterval(anim(j), t));
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">44%</text>
  </svg
  ><svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">20%</text>
  </svg
  ><svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">90%</text>
  </svg
  ><svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">14%</text>
  </svg
  ><svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">60%</text>
  </svg
  ><svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 141 141">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#DD1111" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#710000" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="30px" text-anchor="middle">50%</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: hey chip, im having problems with my code in mozilla using this, are you able to shed any light? Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice plugin [pieProgress.js](https://github.com/amazingSurge/jquery-asPieProgress) to do this. Here is the [demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circle-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-SVG-asPieProgress/) and the [tutorial how to use this.](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Animated-Circle-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-SVG-asPieProgress.html)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried using this and was very quirksome to implement, trying to keep my website plugin free as it slows it down. If needs be, will go back to it