# qt draw an arc between two points using angle in radians

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, trigonometry, qpainterpath

I want to draw an arc between two points. I know position of the two points and the angle in radians.
I succeeded to wrote a little program to calculate the centre of the circle before to effective draw the arc. But when I draw a circle to verify, when I use small values for radians, the circle line do not cross the two points given.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <cmath>
#include <QPainter>

void cross(QPainterPath* path, double x, double y);

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect( 0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0 );
    QPainterPath* path = new QPainterPath();

    double x1, x2, y1, y2, l, rad, r;
    double x3, y3, xx, yy;
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

    //first point
    x1=250;
    y1=250;
    //second point
    x2=350;
    y2=300;
    //radians - play with it. This is low value - this is buggy
    rad=0.002;

    l=sqrt (pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2)); //distance between (x1,y) and (x2,y2)
    u=180.0 * rad / PI; //transform radians in angle
    r=(l/2.0)/sin(rad/2.0); //this is radius

    //point in the middle of (x1,y) and (x2,y2)... half of l
    x3 = (x1+x2)/2;
    y3 = (y1+y2)/2;

    //find center of circle
    if(rad>0){
        xx = x3 + sqrt(pow(r,2)-pow((l/2),2))*(y1-y2)/l;
        yy = y3 + sqrt(pow(r,2)-pow((l/2),2))*(x2-x1)/l;
    }else{
        xx = x3 - sqrt(pow(r,2)-pow((l/2),2))*(y1-y2)/l;
        yy = y3 - sqrt(pow(r,2)-pow((l/2),2))*(x2-x1)/l;
    }


    //draw circle to verify
    path->moveTo(xx, yy);
    path->addEllipse(QRectF(xx-r,yy-r,r*2,r*2));

    cross(path, x3,y3);
    cross(path, xx,yy);
    cross(path, x1,y1);
    cross(path, x2,y2);


    qDebug() << "r =" << r << " xx =" << xx << " yy =" << yy ;
    qDebug() << "Verify r - distance from (x1,y1) to center of circle" << sqrt (pow((x1-xx),2) + pow((y1-yy),2));
    qDebug() << "Verify r - distance from (x2,y2) to center of circle" << sqrt (pow((x2-xx),2) + pow((y2-yy),2));

    scene.addPath(*path);

    QGraphicsView view( &scene );
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}

void cross(QPainterPath* path, double x, double y){
    path->moveTo(x, y-5);
    path->lineTo(x, y+5);
    path->moveTo(x-5, y);
    path->lineTo(x+5, y);
}
```

[image: radians = 1.0] [image: radians = 0.002]

However, the distance from the two points to the circle center is equal to the calculated radius.
where am I wrong?

Comment: Just an aside: a more convenient way to compute cartesian distance between 2 points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` is via [`std::hypot`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) - in this case `std::hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but since it's been viewed 1K times and not been answered I thought I'd weigh in.

I believe the draw ellipse function in QT is using 4 bezier curves to create the shape. There is no perfect way to represent a circle using bezier curves, instead you need to aim for the closest approximation you can get.

For my purposes, I found this [bezier curve circle approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-b%C3%A9zier-curves) Stack Overflow post incredibly helpful. The solution I settled on was to approximate the circle with a high quantity of arcs starting at the point itself to guarantee that my circle appeared to go through it.

Another option is to write your own [bresenham's circle drawing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/) function using the QT painter "drawPoint" function to put the individual pixels. I found that this solution was too slow at increasing zoom levels in my QT app, however, it was incredibly accurate.

Hopefully this helps someone next time this crops up.