# How to Convert android.graphics.Path.arcTo ( oval, startAngle,sweepAngle) to android.graphics.Path.cubicTo()

Tags: android, bezier, cubic-bezier

I have searched a lot about this.Like [how-to-create-circle-with-bézier-curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-b%C3%A9zier-curves), [how-to-best-approximate-a-geometrical-arc-with-a-bezier-curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734076/how-to-best-approximate-a-geometrical-arc-with-a-bezier-curve) etc. But all seems to me as arbitrary approximation of Arc to bezier curve.
Thanks

Comment: It is mathematically impossible to make a circular arc with a Bezier curve, no matter how high-order you pick the curve (because the sinoid function cannot be expressed as a finite polynomial). So it's not "arbitrary": if you need to convert from an arc to a Bezier curve, you literally **have** to approximate the former with the latter. So you end up [having to read up on things like this](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
thanks, your article is awesome, appreciative . I have gone through it. 
It will be really helpful if  you put one example here or there ( approximating an arc to cubic bezier).I am still hesitate to write code as my math is not as good as needed :-) .

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
in below section of the article, i have one doubt 
https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#aligning
how you got the expression after rotation( translation is pretty clear to me that we did minus with same value). But with what value we did rotation and how

Comment: after translating, you can compute the angle that your baseline (start--end) makes with the x-axis using the `atan2` function that pretty much all programming languages come with. If that angle is `a`, then you can now rotate all points around (0,0) by `-a`, which rotates everything so that it aligns with the x-axis You don't *have* to do this, but it makes the maths incredibly much easier.